# communication between an embedded jetty and its parent application

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

i have windows service app and i want to use web interface for my app instead of gui. But i wonder how to make a servlet in jetty communicate with its hosted application - the windows service app.

Thank you.

Comment: What is a windows service app?

Comment: my app is a windows service and i wonder how app like cruise control and continuum have their web interface communicate with the underlying service

Comment: CruiseControl and Continuum are Java apps communicating with Java "services". They can have a windows service wrapper around them that allows for them to be run as windows services, but all the actual "work" is done in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are going from inside a JVM (jetty) to outside the JVM (your service), you will probably have to use sockets, unless you want to delve into JNI (java native interface), but that's probably more work than you want.

I am assuming that your windows service is an actual native windows app and not a Java app with a service wrapper around it.

Good luck.

Comment: No, my windows service is a java app with a wrapper. My problem is how can i provide access to my java app for a webapp run inside jetty.
Thank you.

Comment: Then when you embed jetty you can pass a reference to your service application into it as a ServletContext attribute or something along those lines. Socket connections would still work, though it would be a more complex solution in this case since you can get direct access.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same classloader to solve the problem by:

```
WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext(jetty_home + "/JavaServices", "/JavaServices");
webapp.setDefaultsDescriptor(jetty_home+"/etc/webdefault.xml");
webapp.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());//THIS LINE IS THE KEY
```